# Sharing state between event handlers in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The following code searches `elements` by text. It also sets a `selectedElement` (the first `element` in `elements`).

```
import { useEffect, useState, ChangeEvent } from "react";

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("Initial value");
  const [elements, setElements] = useState<HTMLElement[]>([]);
  const [selectedElement, setSelectedElement] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(
    null
  );

  function findElementsByText(selectors: string, text: string) {
    if (text === "") return [];

    const regex = new RegExp(text);
    const elements = Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(selectors)
    );

    return elements.filter((element) => {
      return element.textContent?.match(regex);
    });
  }

  function handleInputChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const selectors = "abbr";
    const { value } = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const foundElements = findElementsByText(selectors, value);
    const foundSelectedElement = foundElements[0] || null;
    setInputValue(value);
    setElements(foundElements);
    console.log("selectedElement from handleInputChange", foundSelectedElement);
    setSelectedElement(foundSelectedElement);
  }

  function isCommand(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    return event.ctrlKey || event.key === "Enter" || event.key === "Escape";
  }

  function handleDocumentKeyDown(event: any) {
    if (!isCommand(event)) return;

    if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "]") {
      console.log("selectedElement from handleDocumentKeyDown", selectedElement);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="keys">
      <input type="text" onChange={handleInputChange} value={inputValue} />
      <span id="count">
        {selectedElement ? elements.indexOf(selectedElement) + 1 : 0}/
        {elements.length}
      </span>
      <br/>
      <abbr>a</abbr>
      <abbr>b</abbr>
      <abbr>c</abbr>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want `Ctrl + ]` to set `selectedElement` to the next element. To do that, I have to be able to access `selectedElement` inside `handleDocumentKeyDown`.

But if, for example, I type `a` in the `input` (triggering `handleInputChange` and `setSelectedElement()`), then I press `Ctrl + ]` (triggering `handleDocumentKeyDown`), `selectedElement` will be `null`, even though `foundSelectedElement` is `<abbr>a</abbr>`.

I thought when I pressed `Ctrl + ],` I'd already be in the "next render" and therefore I'd be able to access the newest value of `selectedElement` in `handleDocumentKeyDown`. But it wasn't the case.

How to change the code so that `selectedElement` isn't `null` in `handleDocumentKeyDown`, and instead has the HTML element set by `setSelectedElement()` in `handleInputChange`?

Live code:

[image: Edit useState same value rerender (forked)]

Comment: Would you please actually _read_ e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately - there's only so many times you can possibly be surprised by such a straightforward concept as a _closure_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought when I pressed `Ctrl + ]`, I'd already be in the "next render" and therefore I'd be able to access the newest value of `selectedElement` in `handleDocumentKeyDown` (since it's a state).

Comment: Again, it's **closed over**. You've very carefully added the event listener only once, when the component first renders, with your `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem using useRef hook. Here is my solution (In this solution, I used a new ref variable selectedElementRef.):

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, ChangeEvent } from "react";

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("Initial value");
  const [elements, setElements] = useState<HTMLElement[]>([]);
  const [selectedElement, setSelectedElement] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(
    null
  );
  const selectedElementRef = useRef(selectedElement)
  selectedElementRef.current = selectedElement

  function findElementsByText(selectors: string, text: string) {
    if (text === "") return [];

    const regex = new RegExp(text);
    const elements = Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(selectors)
    );

    console.log(elements)

    return elements.filter((element) => {
      return element.textContent?.match(regex);
    });
  }

  function handleInputChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const selectors = "abbr";
    const { value } = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const foundElements = findElementsByText(selectors, value);
    const foundSelectedElement = foundElements[0] || null;
    setInputValue(value);
    setElements(foundElements);
    console.log("selectedElement from handleInputChange", foundSelectedElement);
    setSelectedElement(foundSelectedElement);
  }

  function isCommand(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    return event.ctrlKey || event.key === "Enter" || event.key === "Escape";
  }

  function handleDocumentKeyDown(event: any) {
    if (!isCommand(event)) return;

    if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "]") {
      console.log(
        "selectedElement from handleDocumentKeyDown",
        selectedElementRef.current
      );
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="keys">
      <input type="text" onChange={handleInputChange} value={inputValue} />
      <span id="count">
        {selectedElement ? elements.indexOf(selectedElement) + 1 : 0}/
        {elements.length}
      </span>
      <br />
      <abbr>a</abbr>
      <abbr>b</abbr>
      <abbr>c</abbr>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It's related to javascript closure. We need to use the reference to access the global state variable in the closure in React. For that, I created and used a selectedElementRef variable.